# Suppress line breaks created by RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, jekyll, knitr, github-flavored-markdown

I am using a Rmarkdown (.Rmd) document to generate a markdown (.md) document for use with a Jekyll blog. I use knitr to create the .md file from the .Rmd file and there are additional line breaks in the .md file that were not in the original .Rmd document. These line breaks are not visible when the post displays on [my Jekyll blog](https://jessecambon.github.io/2019/12/08/practical-tidy-evaluation.html), but unfortunately the line breaks are visible when the post displays on [R-Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/practical-tidy-evaluation/).

Is there a way I can configure my knit settings so that additional line breaks are not created when generating my .md document? Links to my Rmarkdown and outputted Markdown file are below for reference.

EDIT - Note that the files linked to below are now updated with the pandoc_args solution suggested below. Before the pandoc_args argument was added to the YAML, the .md file had extra line breaks.

- [**.Rmd file**](https://github.com/jessecambon/jessecambon.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2019-12-8-practical-tidy-evaluation.Rmd)
- [**.md file**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jessecambon/jessecambon.github.io/master/_posts/2019-12-8-practical-tidy-evaluation.md)

Comment: It appears that the problem is happening on r-bloggers end. Other posts also have weird linebreaks around hyperlinks

Comment: It's true that other RSS feeders don't have the same problem (I checked on Feedly and Feedburner and there were no issues). However, my prior post on R-Bloggers didn't have this issue and I think it was because I didn't have extra line breaks in the .MD for that post (and therefore my HTML file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These line breaks are (probably) caused by `pandoc` and can be controlled with the [`--wrap` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-writer-options). You should use `--wrap=none` or `--wrap=preserve`. You can specify such options in the [YAML header](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/output-formats.html):

```
output:
  md_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--wrap=preserve"]
```